# Why does cqlsh fail with LookupError: unknown encoding?

Tags: python, macos, cassandra

I've just installed Cassandra using `brew` on Mac OS X 10.9.4:

```
➜  ~  brew info cassandra
cassandra: stable 2.1.0
http://cassandra.apache.org
/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/2.0.9 (3466 files, 79M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/cassandra.rb
==> Caveats
If you plan to use the CQL shell (cqlsh), you will need the Python CQL library
installed. Since Homebrew prefers using pip for Python packages, you can
install that using:

  pip install cql

To have launchd start cassandra at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/cassandra/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load cassandra now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.cassandra.plist
➜  ~  uname -a
Darwin xxx 13.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

As advised in the above info message, to install `cql` I executed `sudo easy_install pip` followed by `pip install cql`.

With the software installed, upon executing `cqlsh` I'm facing the error:

```
➜  ~  cqlsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 2084, in <module>
    main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 2067, in main
    single_statement=options.execute)
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 509, in __init__
    self.output_codec = codecs.lookup(encoding)
LookupError: unknown encoding:
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some googling and debugging, it turned out that the call to `locale.getpreferredencoding()` expects proper `LC_ALL` as described in [22.2. locale — Internationalization services](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html):

> To maintain compatibility with other platforms, not only the LANG
>   variable is tested, but a list of variables given as envvars
>   parameter. The first found to be defined will be used. envvars
>   defaults to the search path used in GNU gettext; it must always
>   contain the variable name LANG. The GNU gettext search path contains
>   'LANGUAGE', 'LC_ALL', 'LC_CTYPE', and 'LANG', in that order.

On my system `LC_ALL` was set to `pl_PL`:

```
➜  ~  echo $LC_ALL
pl_PL
```

After a change to `LC_ALL` to `pl` or `pl_pl.utf-8` the Cassandra shell `cqlsh` started fine:

```
➜  ~  export LC_ALL=pl_pl.utf-8
➜  ~  cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.9 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

See the thread [Problem start cqlsh on OSX - Lion](http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/problem-start-cqlsh-on-osx-lion) for a sample Python application to check your locale:

```
python -c 'import locale, codecs; encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding(); print encoding; print codecs.lookup(encoding)'
```

Once it's worked fine, the issue can be considered solved.

Comment: +1 Excellent find, and good work in tracking-down a solution.